# read only privilege for a user in mysql work bench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to give permission to a user to access my database using work bench "users and privilege" option. Now i was create a account, I want to give read only permission to this account user. But i confused to give privilege to this user.Please help me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read only using the MySQL Client right? Select a user under "users and privilege" and click the tab "schema privileges". Click "add entry", pick a host and schema. Then al you have to do is check the "select" privilege. This user has read only rights now.